# (ASP.NET MVC4 C#) Insert UNICODE to SQL Server

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, unicode

I'm new to asp.net mvc4 and having a problem:

when I use:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult AddUser(USER user)
    {
        try
        {
            db.USERs.Add(user);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        catch
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Failed");
        }

    }
```

`db` is my `Entities` (or whatever it's called)

in class `USER` I have 2 string properties: `username` & `fullname` (`nvarchar` ~> for storing unicode characters)

For ex, when I input `username = 'admin' and fullname = 'á'` (using form generated by Razor), check record in SQL Server database, I should see `username = 'admin' and fullname = 'á'`

But it shows: `username = 'admin' and fullname = '?'` instead.

My db use collation: `Vietnamese_CI_AS`

The query:

```
 INSERT INTO [USER] ("username", "fullname") 
 VALUES ('admin', N'á')
```

worked fine. I can see that `INSERT` data using mvc (`db.USERs.Add(user)`) do not allow me to put the N' before the `NVARCHAR` string like query ?

Anyone know how to fix this, please help me ??

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is the column defined as `varchar(...)` ? or is it `nvarchar(...)` ?

Comment: This question doesn't relate at all to asp.net, razor or mvc; can you please indicate what data access tool you are using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any data access code should never be writing:

```
 INSERT INTO [USER] ("username", "fullname") 
 VALUES ('admin', N'á')
```

because unicode aside, this is simply a SQL injection risk. Your data access should *actually* be doing something like

```
 INSERT INTO [USER] ("username", "fullname") 
 VALUES (@username, @fullname)
```

adding parameters with those values. You don't make it clear what data access technology you are using, but it *looks* like either EF or LINQ-to-SQL, in which case the ORM *will get this right*. They all know all about unicode, and besides: the *default* (when adding a parameter with a string value) is to pass it over as unicode. You need to actually tell it to *not* do unicode. So I have to conclude that one of:

- the database column is `varchar` instead of `nvarchar`
- the database column *was* `varchar` when you created the ORM model, and you haven't updated the model to tell it that it is now `nvarchar` - so the model is working with what it knows, and adding the parameter as ANSI rather than unicode

Either fix the database column, or update the model to tell it that the column is unicode.

Comment: thank you for helping ^^ but the column was `nvarchar` before i create mvc project. I'm using `Entity Framework`. The query i used in SQL Management studio just to make sure i'm not using the wrong collation so it's not harm i guess ^^

Comment: @SeverusDark then you need to check the EF configuration, to make sure that it is unicode. Honestly, this is the default: you actually need to work quite hard to make it pass ANSI if it doesn't want to.